# Proof of $\pi _2 (x)=\sum_{p \leq \sqrt{x}} \pi(\frac{x}{p}) + O(\frac{x}{(\log x)^2})$

Tags: analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I need to prove that $\pi _2 (x)=\sum_{p \leq \sqrt{x}} \pi(\frac{x}{p}) + O(\frac{x}{(\log x)^2})$ by using and showing that $\pi _2(x)=\sum_{p_1 \leq \sqrt{x}}\sum _{p_1 < p_2 \leq \frac{x}{p_1}}1$. Where $\pi_2(x)$ denotes the number of integers less than $x$ which is composed of presicely two destinct primes.

And regarding the second sum ($\pi _2(x)=\sum_{p_1 \leq \sqrt{x}}\sum _{p_1 < p_2 \leq \frac{x}{p_1}}1$), maybe someone can explain how it should be understood.

Lastly, maybe someone has encountered the function $\pi_2$ before, and know where I can read about it.

Comment: Well, if "which is composed of presicely two primes" means "which is the product of two different primes", that "second sum" makes sense.

Comment: yes, I mean of two different primes, thank you! :) But I still can'ẗ seem to understand the sum. How, for instance, would you calculate it if $x=12$

Comment: I guess (it would be better to say so explicitly) that all your variables $p, p_i$ only take primes as values. So the outer sum is only over $p_1=2, 3$. For $p_1=2$, the inner sum is over $2<p_2\le12/2=6$, so it's $2$ (two primes, $3$  and $5$, in that interval). For $p_1=3$, you have $3<p_2\le12/3=4$, and there are no primes, there. The total is $2+0=2$, then.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. It makes sense to me now. One of my issues was that I thought that 1 counted as a prime in the sum, but I see that it doesn't.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063483/estimation-of-pi-2x-n-leq-xn-p-1p-2-where-p-1-and-p-2-are-two-d) may help clarifying.